# How to clip an image inside a List's row?

Tags: swiftui

I have a list that looks like this:
[image]

with an image and text inside each row.

There are two problems, I want the image to clip inside the row and not extend outside it.

Also, the text is shifted for some reason. Here's the view for each row of the List. You can vaguely see the row view itself in black slightly outside of the image.

```
ZStack {
        Image("akihiko")
            .resizable()
            .frame(width: 500, height: 90.0)                
        Text(artistCard.style.name)
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
            .foregroundColor(.white)
            .font(.headline)
            .padding(
                EdgeInsets(
                    top: 45,
                    leading: 5,
                    bottom: 5,
                    trailing: 5
            )
     }
```

Edit:

Now added an image of what I need it to be, essentially content inside the row clipped by the row itself

[image]

Comment: Hi, can you put a picture showing how it should look? So we have a clear idea of what you want to accomplish?

Comment: Added an image, ignore the shape, I can't photoshop well. But imagine a normal looking iOS row with rounded corner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To clip the image to the cell, you need to remove the `.listRowInsets`, by using

```
.listRowInsets(EdgeInsets())
```

Here's an example:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        List {
            ZStack {
                Image("wave")
                    .resizable()
                    .scaledToFill()
                Text("Fred")
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .font(.headline)
                    .padding(
                        EdgeInsets(top: 45, leading: 5, bottom: 5, trailing: 5)
                    )
            }
            .frame(height: 90)
            .listRowInsets(EdgeInsets())
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Can you make this work with multiple rows? When I tried it they are all connected together and now separate eclipses in each row.

Comment: Add a section with a single cell per object in your list